# Is there SQLAlchemy automigration tool like South for Django?

Tags: python, database, migration, sqlalchemy

Is there SQLAlchemy automigration tool like South for Django?

I looked to [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/) but it doesn't seem to generate sql update scripts automatically or upgrade downgrade DB

Looks like with sqlalchemy-migrate you need to 
a) manually copy your old model to a new file
b) crate new model in application and copy it to a new file
c) write manually create/drop/alter tables in python sqlalchemy extended dialect 
d) generate sql alter script
e) run command to execute alter sql script

As for me it doesn't solve the problem and only adds overhead, as I can simply do d) manually and it will be much faster then do a), b), c) manually just to d) that you can do in one step.

Is there any auto migration libraries for SQLAlchemy like South for Django, or many RoR-like migration tools?

What I need is to change SQLAlchemy model in python app, run tool and it will compare current DB schema to new DB schema that new model should use, and create Alter scripts that I can adjust manually and execute.

Is there any solution like this in Python?

Answer (score 15):

You can perform automatic migrations with [Alembic](https://pypi.org/project/alembic/). I use it in two large-scale projects I am currently working on. The automatic migration generator can recognize:

- Table additions and removals
- Column additions and removals
- Change of nullable status on columns
- Basic changes in indexes, explicitly-named unique constraints, and foreign keys

(see also: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html)

### Install alembic

```
pip install alembic
```

or (depending on the version of Python you are using):

```
pip3 install alembic
```

### Configure alembic

Execute the following command in your project:

```
alembic init alembic
```

This will set up alembic for your project, in a folder called `alembic`.

You will then need to edit the generated `alembic.ini` configuration file.

In the file `env.py`, tell Alembic where to find SQLAlchemy's `metadata` object in your project.

(see also: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#editing-the-ini-file)

### Generate the migration

Simply execute the following command line:

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Message for this migration"
```

Or even (not recommended):

```
alembic revision --autogenerate
```

### Upgrade the database

After this, I upgrade the database with this simple command from the folder containing the  `alembic.ini` configuration file:

```
alembic upgrade head
```

(see also: http://rodic.fr/blog/automatic-migrations-sqlalchemy-alembic/)

Comment: I tried to use `alembic`. I had to insert a sequence for an auto incrementing id and I had to code using SQL for a particular database type. So I dropped it. Furthermore I do not understand its "code repository" style. `South` is much more simple and powerful to use, I do not understand the technical choices of `alembic`'s developers.

Comment: Which engine are you using?

Comment: postgres on my machine, oracle in production. See this: https://coderwall.com/p/ajdngg/adding-a-postgresql-sequence-with-alembic

Comment: +Marco Sulla

That is whole point of Alembic, explicit not implicit. Easiest solution that comes to my mind is different environment variables that change sql syntax that is in use inside of migration.

Comment: Yeah alembic is the "closest" thing to South for SQLAlchemy. But do not expect it to automate more than 20% of the work. I worked on a project that required Flask, and the first migration required having a table A that referred to table B, and B referring to A. It required manual intervention. So yeah...

Answer (score 8):

There is [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) which looks very promising, but the problem is (for now) that the support for SQlite databases is very limited.

Answer (score -1):

No there is none at this moment. Alembic require you to write code regarding adding/deleting/altering table structure or creating/dropping table. So nothing like django south exists for sqlalchemy.

Comment: This is not true, alembic can figure out transformations from current metadata.

Answer (score -4):

Have you looked into using `sqlalchemy-migrate`?
http://shane.caraveo.com/2010/09/13/database-migrations-for-sqlalchemy-part-duex/

Comment: I was able to update DB from the model using the approach from the blog post, but it works ONLY for the simplest models - as soon as you want it to create DB from the model that has FKs, ManyToMany relationships - it fails with strange SQLAlchemy exceptions about nonexistent related tables and their IDs, while the same model EASILY populates DB using the native SQLAlchey create_all() I'm not sure why one works and other not. Looks like SA-migrate doesn't know about related tables when creates the particular table with FK.

Comment: Did you dig into the code and try to fix the bug? I think that sqlalchemy-migrate is the closest you will find to a solution.